# How to get url using path parameter working with Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am making servlet to perfrom crud operation in database and want to use doput and do delete in HttpServlet and and these request are send via postman and uses path parameter so how can I get something which is passed in url or postman? for example we use req.getParameter in doget.

Answer (score -2):

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream());

String data = br.readLine();